# How to query and iterate over array of structures in Athena (Presto)?

Tags: sql, json, amazon-athena, presto

I have a S3 bucket with 500,000+ `json` records, eg.

```
{
  "userId": "00000000001",
  "profile": {
    "created": 1539469486,
    "userId": "00000000001",
    "primaryApplicant": {
      "totalSavings": 65000,
      "incomes": [
        { "amount": 5000, "incomeType": "SALARY", "frequency": "FORTNIGHTLY" },
        { "amount": 2000, "incomeType": "OTHER", "frequency": "MONTHLY" }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I created a new table in Athena

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE profiles (  
  userId string,
  profile struct<
    created:int,
    userId:string,
    primaryApplicant:struct<
      totalSavings:int,
      incomes:array<struct<amount:int,incomeType:string,frequency:string>>,
    >
  >
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 'ignore.malformed.json' = 'true')
LOCATION 's3://profile-data'
```

I am interested in the `incomeTypes`, eg. `"SALARY"`, `"PENSIONS"`, `"OTHER"`, etc.. and ran this query changing `jsonData.incometype` each time:

```
SELECT jsonData
FROM "sampledb"."profiles"

CROSS JOIN UNNEST(sampledb.profiles.profile.primaryApplicant.incomes) AS la(jsonData)

WHERE jsonData.incometype='SALARY'
```

This worked fine with `CROSS JOIN UNNEST` which flattened the incomes array so that the data example above would span across 2 rows. The only idiosyncratic thing was that `CROSS JOIN UNNEST` made all the field names lowercase, eg. a row looked like this:

```
{amount=1520, incometype=SALARY, frequency=FORTNIGHTLY}
```

Now I have been asked how many users have two or more `"SALARY"` entries, eg.

```
      "incomes": [
        { "amount": 3000, "incomeType": "SALARY", "frequency": "FORTNIGHTLY" },
        { "amount": 4000, "incomeType": "SALARY", "frequency": "MONTHLY" }
      ],
```

I'm not sure how to go about this.

1. How do I query the array of structures to look for duplicate `incomeTypes` of `"SALARY"`?
2. Do I have to iterate over the array?
3. What should the result look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`UNNEST` is a very powerful feature, and it's possible to solve this problem using it. However, I think using [Presto's Lambda functions](https://prestodb.github.io/docs/0.172/functions/lambda.html) is more straight forward:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM sampledb.profiles
WHERE CARDINALITY(FILTER(profile.primaryApplicant.incomes, income -> income.incomeType = 'SALARY')) > 1
```

This solution uses [`FILTER`](https://prestodb.github.io/docs/0.172/functions/lambda.html#filter) on the `profile.primaryApplicant.incomes` array to get only those with an `incomeType` of `SALARY`, and then [`CARDINALITY`](https://prestodb.github.io/docs/0.172/functions/array.html#cardinality) to extract the length of that result.

---

Case sensitivity is never easy with SQL engines. In general I think you should not expect them to respect case, and many don't. Athena in particular [explicitly converts column names to lower case](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/tables-databases-columns-names.html).

Comment: Thanks for explaining and offering a great solution @Theo. This was a very fast and effective.

Answer (score 4):

You can combine [`filter`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#filter) with [`cardinality`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#cardinality) to filter array elements having `incomeType = 'SALARY'` more than once.

This can be further improve so that intermediate array is not materialized by using [`reduce`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#reduce) (see examples in the docs; I'm not quoting them here, since they do not directly answer your question).

Comment: Thanks @PiotrFindeisen. Theo had similar thoughts.